# Creating files permission denied in WinSCP with FTP but not with SFTP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ftp, winscp

I am using Ubuntu server edition 14.04 and installed `vsftpd`. I have created a new user `in0006` with home directory `/var/www/localdev/in0006/` and I have set `chroot_local_user=YES` in `vsftpd.conf` file so that the user `in0006` can access only to the particular folder `/var/www/localdev/in0006/` through FTP.

I use WinSCP as FTP client. I logged in to WinSCP with the user `in0006` and it I have the access only to the particular folder. The problem is I can't copy any file or create folder with the user `in0006` through WinSCP.

**user rights**

```
/var/www/localdev         rwxrwxrwx  administrator  administrator
/var/www/localdev/in0006  rwxrwxrwx  in0006         administrator
```

Comment: Why are you using FTP if you can use WinSCP?  Using SFTP or SCP will provide you with much better security.  What happens if you use SSH and try to create/move the file?  (Does that show any error messages?)

Comment: It works fine with SSH and even it works when I use SFTP with winscp but I can access to all folders and files in sftp. Why it is not working with FTP? What i am missing with?

Comment: Recommendation 1: Trash FTP.  Just use SFTP if you can.  However, if you wish to pursue this anyway, find the program that is listening to TCP port 21 (presumably "ftpd"), and see what username is running that command.  "ps -auxww | grep ftp" may help... or you might need to lose the hyphen and/or some of the letters that come right after it, depending on what version of ps your operating system is using.